# Renamed Variable in MonoDevelop broke iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode4.2, monodevelop

I renamed a variable in MonoDevelop, compiled fine, carried over to xCode fine, but when trying to run the simulator I can't open the app. Is there any behind the scenes propogation that has to take place when changing variables?

Mick

Answer (score 0):

If the variable was an outlet, you'll have to reconnect the object to it in Xcode. MonoDevelop doesn't currently propagate renames into xibs.